# Use custom requests in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website which requires the `Connection: close` header to be removed. But scrapy by default adds `Connection: close` header to all requests and cannot be overridden.

So instead I'm trying to use custom requests to make the requests without the `Connection: close` header. But I'm getting errors.

Is there a way to use custom requests instead of `scrapy.Request` or subclass the scrapy.Request to remove the `Connection: close` header?

Scrapy spider:

```
import scrapy
import requests


class AdidasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "adidas"

    def start_requests(self):

        url = 'http://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes'

        headers = {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Host": "www.adidas.com",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
        }

        yield requests.get(url, headers=headers, hooks={'response': self.parse})

    def parse(r, *args, **kwargs):
        print r
```

I'm getting a lot of errors:

```
2018-01-28 14:58:08 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.request_scheduled of <scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware object at 0x04D30C30>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\signal.py", line 30, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 343, in request_scheduled
    redirected_urls = request.meta.get('redirect_urls', [])
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta'
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 285, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1243, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1252, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 135, in _next_request
    self.crawl(request, spider)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 210, in crawl
    self.schedule(request, spider)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 216, in schedule
    if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scheduler.py", line 54, in enqueue_request
    if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'

2018-01-28 14:58:08 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 285, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1243, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1252, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 878, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 135, in _next_request
    self.crawl(request, spider)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 210, in crawl
    self.schedule(request, spider)
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 216, in schedule
    if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
  File "d:\work\freelance\shopify_monitor\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scheduler.py", line 54, in enqueue_request
    if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)
```

`requests` returns you a response and in this case you are just `yield`ing it to `start_requests`. That's why you are getting errors related to responses.